# Link DB in Oracle parameter problem

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, oracle, parameters

I've got this Oracle query that links to another db but it doesn't seem to accept my parameters that i pass to the query

Here's my code

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM table1@dev tb1 join table2 tb2 on tb1.id = tb2.id WHERE tb1.id = :id"

cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text

cmd.BindByName = True

cmd.Parameters.Add(New OracleParameter("id", id))
```

I get this error when do this

> ORA-03113: end-of-file on communication channel

But if i simply change the query to not be using parameters then it works

Any ideas on how I could get this working with parameters?

**EDIT**

On further investigation if I try the following

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM table1@dev tb1 WHERE tb1.id = :id"

cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text

cmd.BindByName = True

cmd.Parameters.Add(New OracleParameter("id", id))
```

I get a different error

> ORA-28511: lost RPC connection to heterogeneous remote agent

I would really like a solution which allows parameters to be passed to the linked db but I can't seem to find anything about using parameters with linked db's

Thanks

Comment: Hi, this doesn't look like a query parameter problem but rather a DBLink configuration problem, it looks like you are using a DBLink to a database other than Oracle, is that true? please add your tnsnames.ora and the DBLink creation script. 

On the other hand, does the query work without the where condition?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ORA-03113` is a generic exception, hurled when something catastrophic causes the connection to drop.  There may be some additional information in the alert log or a trace file.  Check the background dump or diagnostics directory.

`ORA-28511` is rather more specific.  The error message points to a particular area for investigation;  the advice is "Check for network problems and remote host crashes. The problem is probably in the agent software. "

So, it's not really a syntax problem.  It's an environment (configuration/hardware) issue.  I'm afraid you're going to have to do a some more digging.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks - it turns out its a problem to with our EasySoft driver or something - they are looking into it now :)

Answer (score 3):

have you tried specifying the parameter type ?:

```
OracleParameter p1 = new OracleParameter("id",OracleDbType.Decimal); 
p1.Value=id; 
cmd.Parameters.Add(p1);
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay in getting back to you - this doesn't seems to make a difference - any other ideas?

Comment: or how about adding Direction = ParameterDirection.Input

Comment: Thanks again for the suggestions but still nothing seems to work... I can't find any documentation for adding parameters for linked databases

Comment: perhaps it does not like the @ I wonder if creating a view on table1@dev and selecting from that makes any difference ?

Comment: I created a view as you suggested but it seems to be giving the same error - I appreciate your help so far :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3248/discussion-between-jamie-taylor-and-kevin-burton)

Answer (score 0):

Personally, this whole Oracle driver/query stuff really made me go nuts; e.g. I experienced that certain [`SELECT *` generated a `DivideByZeroException`](http://blog.magerquark.de/2010-06/resolving-the-oracle-odac-net-error-message-attempted-to-divide-by-zero/) while replacing the `*` by the really required column names worked like a charm.

It *could* be that you have a similar issue here.

What helped me resolving the issues was to choose the ODP.NET drivers really wisely; we are running a production system here with beta drivers since they were the only ones working in all circumstances in our project.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but unfortunately it doesn't seem to make any difference